# Export results from DB2 to CSV including column names via bash

Tags: bash, shell, db2, sh

This question branches off a question already asked.

I want to make a csv file with the db2 results including column names.

```
EXPORT TO ...
SELECT 1 as id, 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 as id, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM myTable)
ORDER BY id
```

While this does work, I am left with an unwanted column and rows of 1 and 2's

Is there a way to do this via the db2 command or a full bash alternative without redundant columns while keeping the header at the top?

e.g.

`Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
 data 1      data 2      data3
 ...         ...         ...`

instead of:

`1    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
 2    data 1      data 2      data3
 2    ...         ...         ...`

Comment: Can you post a short extract of what you get, and another one of what you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the headers for the extracted data and you want those headers to always be on top and you want to be able to change the names of those headers so it appears more user-friendly and put it all into a CSV file.

You can do the following:

```
# Creates headers and new output file
HEADERS="ID,USERNAME,EMAIL,ACCOUNT DISABLED?"
echo "$HEADERS" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"

# Gets results from database 
db2 -x "select ID, USERNAME, DISABLED FROM ${SCHEMA}.USER WHERE lcase(EMAIL)=lcase('$USER_EMAIL')" | while read ID USERNAME DISABLED ;
do

  # Appends result to file
  echo "${ID},${USERNAME},${USER_EMAIL},${DISABLED}" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"

done
```

No temporary files or merging required.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers I've seen use two separate export statements. The first generates the column headers:

```
db2 "EXPORT TO /tmp/header.csv of del  
SELECT 
SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME c,colname) 
ORDER BY colno) AS VARCHAR(1500)),'<C>',', '),'</C>',''),3) 
FROM syscat.columns WHERE tabschema=${SCHEMA} and tabname=${TABLE}"
```

then the query body

```
db2 "EXPORT TO /tmp/body.csv of del  
SELECT * FROM ${SCHEMA}.${TABLE}"
```

then

```
cat /tmp/header.csv /tmp/body.csv > ${TABLE}.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows lacks a (long overdue) simple opting (to the export command) for this common requirement.

But using the bash shell you can run two separate exports (one for the column-headers, the other for the data ) and concat the results to a file via an intermediate named pipe.

Using an intermediate named pipe means you don't need two flat-file copies of the data.

It is ugly and awkward but it works.

Example fragment (you can initialize the variables to suit your environment):

```
mkfifo ${target_file_tmp}
(( $? != 0 )) && print "\nERROR: failed to create named pipe ${target_file_tmp}" && exit 1

db2 -v "EXPORT TO ${target_file_header} of del SELECT 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 "

cat ${target_file_header} ${target_file_tmp} >> ${target_file} & 
(( $? > 0 )) && print "Failed to append ${target_file} . Check permissions and free space" && exit 1

db2 -v "EXPORT TO ${target_file_tmp} of del SELECT  COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM myTable ORDER BY 1 "
rc=$?
(( rc == 1 )) && print "Export found no rows matching the query" && exit 1
(( rc == 2 )) && print "Export completed with warnings, your data might not be what you expect" && exit 1
(( rc > 2 )) && print "Export failed. Check the messages from export" && exit 1
```

Comment: I like the error checking. mkfifo however, was causing the script to hang. Must the catination occur between the two exports as in your example or does it not matter?

Comment: Works fine for me. What operating-system are you using? When using a pipe, both ends must be open, hence the 'cat' is happening in the background reading from the pipe, while the export happens in another process and is writing into the pipe.

Comment: Running it on linux. If I declare mkfifo ${target_file_tmp}, then db2 -v "EXPORT TO ${target_file_tmp} of del SELECT ... " will hang. If I remove it, it works as intended. Odd I know. Unless it's needed or recommended I will go without. The shell script is located and run from the db2 linux box, I use putty to connect to and run it.

Comment: Check the umask of the account that runs the script. The instance-owner account needs to be able to write to the pipe. Verify that the 'cat' action happens in the background (see the & at end of the command-line of cat) so both ends of the pipe are concurrently open.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your simple case

```
EXPORT TO ...
SELECT C1, C2, C3 FROM (
SELECT 1 as id, 'COL1' as C1, 'COL2' as C2, 'COL3' as C3 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 as id, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM myTable)
)
ORDER BY id
```

Longer term, `EXTERNAL TABLE` support (already in Db2 Warehouse) which has the `INCLUDEHEADER` option is (I guess) going to appear in Db2 at some point.

Comment: Not really as this still leaves me with a column of 1 and 2's which I don't want.

Comment: You can ORDER BY columns that are not in the SELECT clause. That is what I did above, and if you try it you should see that the `id` is not selected and not in the output even though the rows are ordered by `id`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a stored procedure that extracts the header via describe command. The names can be retrieved from a temporary table, and be exported to a file. The only thing it is still not possible is to concatenate the files via SQL, thus a cat to both file and redirection to another file is necessary as last step.

```
CALL DBA.GENERATE_HEADERS('SELECT * FORM SYSCAT.TABLES') @
EXPORT TO myfile_header OF DEL SELECT * FROM SESSION.header @
EXPORT TO myfile_body OF DEL SELECT * FORM SYSCAT.TABLES @
!cat myfile_header myfile_body > myfile @
```

The code of the stored procedure is at: https://gist.github.com/angoca/8a2d616cd1159e5d59eff7b82f672b72
More information at: https://angocadb2.blogspot.com/2019/11/export-headers-of-export-in-db2.html.